# Optional Int property contains nil instead of zero during migration

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-migration

I am trying to perform Realm.IO migration from the following model:

```
public class RealmBuddy: Object {
    dynamic var id = 0
    let contactId = RealmOptional<Int>()
    dynamic var name = ""
    let topics = List<RealmTopic>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

to the following:

```
public class RealmBuddy: Object {
    dynamic var id = 0
    dynamic var contactId: String? = nil
    dynamic var name = ""
    let topics = List<RealmTopic>()

    override public static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

As you can see, the single change is in the type of contactId: optional `Int` should be converted to optional `String`. I've implemented it like this:

```
if (oldSchemaVersion < 1) {
    migration.enumerate(RealmBuddy.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
        if let contactId = oldObject!["contactId"] as? Int {
            newObject!["contactId"] = "\(contactId)"
        }
    }
}
```

However, I found that after migration my entities which had no contactId (i.e. `nil` value) now have contactId equal to "0" string. It appears that oldObject!["contactId"] returns 0 instead of nil.

I haven't find any info or examples on how to perform this simple task so I am not sure if I retrieve/cast the value properly (tried to cast to `RealmOptional<Int>` also), so I decided to ask about it here before filing an issue on github. **Is it a bug or expected behavior? If it is expected behavior, how to get value properly?**

**PS:** My project is open-source because I am new to iOS and develop it for self-education, so I pushed it to a [repo](https://github.com/romanzes/dont-forget-to-say-ios/tree/migration_issue) where the issue can be easily reproduced (please note that it is in **migration_issue** branch). I also made a [unit test](https://github.com/romanzes/dont-forget-to-say-ios/blob/migration_issue/Dont%20Forget%20To%20Say%20Tests/MigrationTests.swift) using existing `.realm` file which migrates to new schema during test. Hope that will help.

**PPS:** I tried 0.102.1 and 0.103.1 versions of the library.

**PPPS:** It was mentioned that Realm Browser doesn't display any contactId with nil value in my sample .realm file. I think it is just Realm Browser issue, so I made another [unit test](https://github.com/romanzes/dont-forget-to-say-ios/blob/test_v0_realm/Dont%20Forget%20To%20Say%20Tests/RealmDataStoreTests.swift) in separate branch to prove that old database *has* nil value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug. See https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/pull/3643. Fixed in 0.103.2.

> Optional properties of scalar types were getting the wrong Objective-C
>   type code, leading to the dynamic accessors taking the non-optional
>   code path. This resulted in nil values being returned as 0.

Answer (score 0):

When I open default-v0.realm in the Realm Browser I don't see any rows with a null `contactId`. If you're expecting there to be one then the problem is in the code that initially populated the Realm and not the migration code.

Comment: I also had this idea when I tried to open the database in Realm Browser. However, when I load given .realm file via code, there *is* nil value - record with name "Roman Petrenko" has it. Other contact ("Kate Bell") has contactId == 1. So I think Realm Browser just can't display nil values yet.

Comment: I updated my answer and repo to demonstrate the presence of nil values in default-v0.realm